# Polymer accessing function of dynamically created component

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I have a `my-createCrewModal` component that is supposed to be created once a function from a `my-createcrew` component is called. The modal is supposed to appear to show a particular text then disapear after 4 seconds.

`my-createcrew.html`

```
// function to create a crew
_createCrew: function() {
crewName = this.$.crewname.value;
// handled with the main app file;
this.fire('add-new-crew', {
  name: crewName
 });
}
```

`my-createCrewModal.html` open and close functions..

```
Polymer({
  is: 'my-createCrewModal',

  open: function() {
    Polymer.dom.flush();
    this.offsetHeight && this.classList.add('opened');
    this.debounce('_close', this.close, 4000);
  },

  close: function() {
    this.classList.remove('opened');
  }
});
```

and the

`my-app.html`

```
  // on add new crew
  _onAddNewCrew: function(event) {
    if (!this._createCrew) {
      this._createCrew = document.createElement('my-createCrewModal');
      Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(this._createCrew);
    }
     Polymer.dom(this._createCrew).innerHTML = 'New Item Added';
    this._createCrew.open();
  },
```

the listener object
looks like this

```
  listeners: {
    'add-new-crew': '_onAddNewCrew'
  },
```

When I call the function I get

`Uncaught TypeError: this._createCrew.open is not a function`

Why does it not see the open function in the `my-createCrewModal` component.

What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you test it without camel case component id? Use my-create-crew-modal instead and see if the problem solves

Comment: Not working. I had tried that the first time

Comment: Have you imported my-createCrewModal.html?

Comment: You are right.. I had not imported it.. :)